# SceneKit move:to action not working in a sequence of action after a scale action

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to do the following on a node which is a simple sphere, without a physicsbody, created in the scenekit editor :

```
    let ScaleDown = SCNAction.scale(to: 0, duration: 1)
    let ScaleUp = SCNAction.scale(to: 0.4, duration: 2)
    let Move = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3.init(InitialCharacterGridCoordinates.x, 0, InitialCharacterGridCoordinates.y), duration: 0)
    CharacterNode.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([ScaleDown, Move, ScaleUp]))
```

The problem is that the Move action doesn't do anything. However if I do as below it works :

```
    CharacterNode.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([Move, ScaleDown, ScaleUp]))
```

I have also tried with all types of physicsbody, it does not work neither. It seems that as soon as a scale action is executed, the move action is not working, when in a sequence. Outside of a sequence, it is working.

Any clue ?

J.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results for either combination using the code below.  I can't see your original position coordinates, but possibly you are moving to a position that you already occupy?

```
            ship.position = SCNVector3Make(5, 0, 5)
            let ScaleDown = SCNAction.scale(to: 0, duration: 1)
            let ScaleUp = SCNAction.scale(to: 0.4, duration: 1)
            let Move = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3.init(5, 0, 5), duration: 1)
            let Home = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3.init(0, 0, 0), duration: 1)
            ship.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([ScaleDown, Move, ScaleUp, Home, Move, ScaleDown, ScaleUp]))
```